# Change what "ttt_radio traitor" says in GMod

Tags: garrys-mod

I want `ttt_radio traitor` to say something else than `[name] is a traitor!`

I've seen people do it with `ttt_radio imwith` where they changed it to `I see [name]`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but you can change the binds for things like this in `/directory_path_to_game/lang/english.lua` (if you're running a server with a foreign language, then substitute english.lua for *language*.lua) and it should be located on `L.quick_traitor`.

Comment: This doesn't really help, it just tells how to re-bind

Comment: I'm not sure what the right wording would be, but it is the correct answer. "[name] is a traitor!" is bound to L.quick_traitor located in english.lua by default. Example: https://github.com/garrynewman/garrysmod/blob/a4621b3b9d6e60b507de1a84eef5759d4787fdb2/garrysmod/gamemodes/terrortown/gamemode/lang/english.lua line 164.

Comment: Ohh, I see! Isn't that client-side?

Comment: Just tested, this works server-side as well.

Comment: It's serverside, but all clients come with the gamemode by default now (still, all changes done to the core on the host will show up to anyone even if they have the gamemode).

Answer (score 2):

I think they just used the see name.

The console command used to send a quickchat is "ttt_radio". You need to supply which quickchat text to send by adding its name, for example: "ttt_radio help" to send the "Help!" chat. Binding that to a key could look like:

```
bind "h" "ttt_radio help"
```

Entered into the console of course. These are the possible quickchat names:

```
Name    Text
yes     Yes.
no      No.
help    Help!
imwith  I'm with (player you aim at).
see     I see (player you aim at).
traitor (player you aim at) is the traitor!
suspect (player you aim at) acts suspicious.
check   Anyone still alive?
```

Source: http://ttt.badking.net/help

So basically you have to bind "key" "ttt_radio name" in the console and it shouts the text when you press that key

Comment: Yeah but I want to make a custom ttt_radio command so that I can say `[name] is shooting me!` in red letters without having to type the name. Currently I bound `ttt_radio traitor;say The person I just called out is shooting me, KOS!`, but it's too much of a work-around for me.